# 284: A subquery has returned not exactly one row

Tags: sql, informix

I'm trying to do an update massive to a table in INFORMIX, but my query returns this error:

```
284: A subquery has returned not exactly one row
```

This is my query:

```
update newLocations set
       description=
             (select unique b.description from newLocations a,locations b
             where a.id_location=b.id_location )
```

Here are mi locations table

```
Table: locations        
id_location id2_location    description
02          AAA00           AS-LOC1 
05          AA000           AS-LOC2
10          AA010           AS-LOC7
20          AA020           AS-LOC8
30          AA030           AS-LOC9
40          AA040           AS-LOCA
50          AA050           AS-LOCB
```

Here are mi newLocations table

```
Table: newLocations     
id_location description
02          
05          
05          
05          
05          
05          
10          
20          
30          
40          
50
```

My subquery returns:

```
AS-LOC1 
AS-LOC2
AS-LOC7
AS-LOC8
AS-LOC9
AS-LOCA
AS-LOCB
```

How can I do to assign the description in newLocations, relating id_location from locations?

This is the solution, thanks to Joseph B

```
update newLocations 
  set description=
       (select max(l.description)
       from locations l
       where newLocations.id_location=l.id_location)
  where exists
  (select 1
   from locations l2
   where newLocations.id_location=l2.id_location);
```

And this error:

```
 201: A syntax error has occurred.
```

Comment: Location 05 has several different descriptions.  Which one did you want?  AS-LOC2, AS-LOC3, AS_LOC4 etc...  Without ID2_Location in newLOcations, and having that as part of the update, you simply can't do what you're trying to do.  The engine doesn't know which 05 to set to what description, even though they may have the same counts.

Comment: Sorry, mi table was wrong. There's unique id_location in locations

Comment: what data is returned by the subquery by itself: select unique b.description from newLocations a,locations b
             where a.id_location=b.id_location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
update newLocations nl
set description=
             (select MAX(l.description) 
              from locations l
              where nl.id_location=l.id_location )
where exists
(select 1 
from locations l2
where nl.id_location=l2.id_location);
```

Here's a **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dbb5a/1)** using PostgreSQL.

Comment: @user1600801 Is that the complete error message? The table aliases are l and l2 (and not 1 and 12) (just to make sure).

Comment: The aliases are right. And yes, that's all my error message

Comment: I've found the problem. The error was from the alias from the update

Comment: simply using the MAX function worked for me. Thanks!